# Conditionally add class to image by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, addclass

This JS replace image file name `default.jpg` to `hqdefault.jpg` from all images below. But now I'm trying to add class to Image, if Image **src** has `img.youtube.com` link on images by extending this JS.

**JS:**

```
$('#selector img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="selector">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/qDc_5zpBj7s/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ss7EJ-PW2Uk/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/ktd4_rCHTNI/default.jpg">
    <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/0GTXMEPDpps/default.jpg">
</div>
```

Means, If image src has Youtube image then add a class `.video` to parent image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#selector img').each(function(i) {
    var self = $(this);
    var src = self.attr('src');
    if (src.match(/img.youtube.com/)) {
        self.attr('src', src.replace("/default.jpg","/hqdefault.jpg"));
        self.addClass('video');
    }
});
```

Comment: How add class to image?

Comment: `$(this).addClass('myClassName')`

Comment: but, by extending my JS

Comment: @Aabira I've added addClass

Answer (score 1):

You can add a condition before replacing and add video class.

```
$('#selector img').attr('src',function(i,e){
    if($(this).attr('src').search('img.youtube.com') > 0){
         $(this).addClass('video');
    }
    return $(this).attr('src').replace("default.jpg","hqdefault.jpg");
});
```

Comment: do not change attributes in condition! it answers the question but is bad practice i think

Comment: @Chris using search does not change any attributes. I am just getting it and replace can be inside if condition if replacement is needed just only for youtube. Correct me chris If i misunderstood.

Comment: what i mean: this function is for changing the source attribute. but you add a class in the function that is for changing the src attribute. in my eyes this is bad practice.